# How to redirect after a login in webview?

Tags: android, redirect, webview

I am developing an android application . I used Webview to create UI and ajax to connect to server . There is a login.html file that have two text inputs and sends username and password to server and if server returns success it redirects to index.html file . Unfortunately it doesn't redirect to index.html . In android emulator works but in Android 6 mobiles it doesn't work . any body knows how to redirect in webview in this situation ?

```
        var username = $("#username").val();
        var password = $("#password").val();
        var params = { "username": username, "password": password };
        $.getJSON("http://warehouse-abforce.rhcloud.com/api/v1/login", params, function (data) {
            document.getElementById("wait").style.visibility = 'hidden';
            if (data["success"] == "true") {
                window.localStorage.setItem("name_user", data["name"]);
                window.localStorage.setItem("username", $("#username").val());
                window.localStorage.setItem("password", $("#password").val());
                if (navigator.userAgent.match(/Android/i))
                    document.location = "index.html";
                else
                  window.location.replace("index.html");

            });
```

Comment: which version of Android os is installed on emulator?

Comment: android 6 .  It redirects in emulator but it doesn't redirect in mobile .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

finally I found solution .
I should add this code to my java code . wv is my webview object . shouldOverrideUrlLoading must be implemented and it returns false .
Now it works well in both mobile and emulator of version 6 . It redirects to second page successuly .

```
 wv.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
     @Override
     public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
         return false;
     }
});
```